# How to perform a series of controls while a condition is not yet met

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm looking for an efficient way to perform a series of controls (about 40) that should be interrupted as soon as one control identifies that a cell contains an inadequate value. This will be done in Google Sheets to identify what lines are ready to be exported.

I thought of using a loop but I don't think I can use a classic form of loops here since I don't repeat the same control over and over.

So here is how I could code it:

```
var rowsToExport = [];
var i = 0;

for (row = 0; row < 1000; row++){

    if (cellA.value == X && 
        cellB.value == Y && 
        cellC.value == Z && 
        ... etc (40 times)
       ) {

            rowsToExport[i] = row;
            i++;
    }
}
```

I assume that this isn't efficient. The reasoning is to save time and not go through the whole list of controls if a problem was identified in the earlier checks.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you post the *actual* repetitive code (a few lines of it), rather than `Xa` over and over again (which won't do anything)?

Comment: Hi, I haven't coded it yet. The controls don't matter, my question is about the best method to do this kind of things. Thanks :)

Comment: It's not so clear what the logic (or nature of the repetitiveness) is exactly, hard to come up with example code

Comment: Hope it's more clear this way. I just want to know if it's possible to not perform the other 39 checks if the first one is wrong. I ask this because I assume it's not efficient and shouldn't be done. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, if the first condition fails, it won't go through all the other checks. The interpreter will know the result will be false at that point.

Comment: Ah ok ! Didn't know it worked this way. Thanks :)